# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE only shows tables from the same catalog

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, information-schema

I'm working with a database that has many cross-database views. While INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS lists all these views, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE do not.

All views in question are in this format:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Invoice]
AS SELECT * FROM [otherdb].[dbo].[Invoice]
```

The following query returns 0 rows:

```
SELECT
    VIEW_CATALOG
    ,VIEW_SCHEMA
    ,VIEW_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG <> VIEW_CATALOG
```

Leaving the appropriateness of SELECT * for another discussion, why are the external database references not in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views and is there any way to get them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [stop using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for various reasons](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information-schema-views.aspx), including one I didn't mention in that post (yet), which is the fact that they don't handle cross-database dependencies.

Use the catalog views and dynamic management functions instead.

To get just the views, you can use [`sys.sql_expression_dependencies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx):

```
SELECT 
  [schema] = s.name, 
  [view]   = v.name, 
  d.referenced_database_name, 
  d.referenced_schema_name,
  d.referenced_entity_name
FROM sys.views AS v
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON v.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
ON v.[object_id] = d.referencing_id
WHERE d.referenced_database_name IS NOT NULL;
```

To get the column names too, you can use [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185.aspx):

```
SELECT 
  [schema] = s.name, 
  [view]   = v.name, 
  r.referenced_database_name,
  r.referenced_schema_name,
  r.referenced_entity_name,
  [column] = r.referenced_minor_name
FROM sys.views AS v
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON v.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities
(
   QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(v.name), N'OBJECT'
) AS r
WHERE r.referenced_database_name IS NOT NULL
AND r.referenced_minor_name IS NOT NULL;
```