# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE is inaccurate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Good morning All,

Trying to find dependencies on specific tables.  Used

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE...
```

The above query appeared to confirm my assumption; however when I ran

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE...
```

The results were inaccurate!

I checked the definition of some of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE`, and it doesn't reference the tables in question.  Why is it wrong?!

Already checked out this post - Thanks Aaron Bertrand!

[INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE only shows tables from the same catalog](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121510/information-schema-view-table-usage-only-shows-tables-from-the-same-catalog)

Comment: [Further Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).

Comment: Thanks! Bertrand is the Man!  This was a frightful line from that article - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx says:
"Do not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to determine the schema of an object. The only reliable way to find the schema of a object is to query the sys.objects catalog view." The warning really should state that the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are incomplete...